# Why onSnapshot() executed last?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create Register function in Javascript that uploads the registration information on Firebase Firestore and logs it to the console when the upload is finished.

- I want my console to workflow to be like this: log data from Firestore to console -> set item to localStorage -> alert -> redirect to another page
- But somehow the flow goes like this: set item to localStorage -> alert -> redirect to another page (and never log data from Firestore to console)
- When I omit the redirection, the flow goes: set item to localStorage -> alert -> log data from Firestore to console

I also want to include the user ID in the data uploaded to Firestore. How can I get it?

Please explain to me why this happened, and what I can do to achieve the wanted result. Thanks for your

Code snippet

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.2/firebase-auth.js';
import { collection, onSnapshot, addDoc } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.2/firebase-firestore.js";

import { auth, isArtist, firestore } from "./firebase-config.js";

// if isArtist: profile(publish, no playlist)
// if !isArtist: profile(no publish, playlist)
isArtist();

const Register = async (auth, email, password) => {
  let isChecked;
  let info;
  try {
    const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    isChecked = true;
  } catch (error) {
    isChecked = false;
    info = error.code;
  }
  return {
    info, 
    isChecked,
  };
};

const RegisterPage = () => {
    document.getElementById("btn-register").onclick = async () => {
        let email = document.getElementById('email-register').value;
        let password = document.getElementById('password-register').value;
        let username = document.getElementById('username-register').value;
        let isArtist = localStorage.getItem("isArtist");
        // let user = userCredential.user;

        const isSuccess = await Register(auth, email, password);
        // Inheritance of OOP: isChecked is a local variable of Register
        // After assigning Register to isSuccess -> isSuccess can use isChecked
        if (isSuccess.isChecked) {
            // Compile acc info
            const data = {
              dateRegistration: Date.now(),
              // userID: user.uid,
              email,
              username,
              isArtist,
            };
            // Upload acc info to Firestore
            const colRef = collection(firestore, "accounts");
            addDoc(colRef, data)
              .then(() => {
                // Kiểm tra Firestore
                onSnapshot(colRef, (snapshot) => {
                  const output = [];
                  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                      output.push({...doc.data()});
                  });
                  console.log(output);
                });

                localStorage.setItem("email", email);
                alert("Register successful");
                window.location.href = "home.html";
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                alert("Error uploading data to Firestore:", error);
              })  
        } else {
            alert("Register fail");
        }
    };
};

RegisterPage();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because JavaScript does not wait the execution of the callback passed to the `onSnapshot()` to complete before going to the next line.

Since, in your case, you want to get the collections documents only once, you should use the asynchronous [`getDocs()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) method as follows. Note how we manage the asynchronicity of the different calls to Firebase methods by using `await`:

```
// ...
if (isSuccess.isChecked) {
  // Compile acc info
  const data = { ...};
  // Upload acc info to Firestore
  const colRef = collection(firestore, "accounts");
  await addDoc(colRef, data); // Your function is async, so use await!

  const snapshot = await getDocs(colRef);  // See the await keyword

  const output = [];
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    output.push({ ...doc.data() });
  });
  console.log(output);

  localStorage.setItem("email", email);
  alert("Register successful");
  window.location.href = "home.html";
} else {
  alert("Register fail");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. May I ask why JS does not wait for the execution of the callback passed to the onSnapshot() to complete  before going to the next line?